# Comparision of a regexp in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, comparison, compare, case-sensitive

I want to make a case sensitive comparision like this:

```
If ARGV[0].eql? /word/i
  print "yep! ^^"
elsif 
  print "nope :("
end
```

But that don't works... Don't recognizes "word"
I've tryed too quoteing and escaping chars...

What i'm doing wrong?

Thankyou

Comment: Case sensitive or insensitive? the `i` option makes it insensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you should use =~ operator, then

```
"word" =~ /word/i
```

works fine

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to compare a regex to a string. By changing `/word/i` to `'word'` it should work.